# Using macros in printf function in VS2013 vs VS2017

Tags: c++, user-defined-literals

I have defined this macro in my source code

```
#define UINT_08X_FORMAT   "%08X"
```

I need to use the above in printf like this:

```
printf("Test - "UINT_08X_FORMAT"", 50);
```

It compiles and works fine in VS2013 where as in VS2017, it throws the following compile error.

> invalid literal suffix 'UINT_08X_FORMAT'; literal operator or literal
>   operator template 'operator ""UINT32_FORMAT' not found

How to use the macro in printf.

> Note: I dont want to change the macro definition as it works fine with
>   VS2013. I need a common solution which will work on both VS2013 and
>   VS2017.

Comment: It works fine on my VS2017.

Comment: It works for me in VS2017 if I compile as C, but I get the error if I compile as C++.

Comment: Sorry. It fails to compile on C++. But same succeeds on VS2013

Comment: Couldnt you use `#define UINT_08X_FORMAT %08x` and then just use it inside the string itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++11 added support for user defined literals (UDL), which are triggered by adding a suffix to some other literal (in this case a string literal).  You can overcome it by adding spaces around your macro name to force the newer C++ compiler to treat it as a separate token instead of a UDL suffix:

```
printf("Test - " UINT_08X_FORMAT "", 50);
```

See this note from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal:

> Since the introduction of user-defined literals, the code that uses
>   format macro constants for fixed-width integer types with no space
>   after the preceding string literal became invalid:
>   `std::printf("%"PRId64"\n",INT64_MIN);` has to be replaced by
>   `std::printf("%" PRId64"\n",INT64_MIN);`
>
> Due to maximal munch, user-defined integer and floating point literals
>   ending in p, P, (since C++17) e and E, when followed by the operators
>   + or -, must be separated from the operator with whitespace in the source

Comment: For clarification, change `printf("Test - "UINT_08X_FORMAT"", 50);` to `printf("Test - " UINT_08X_FORMAT "", 50);`. Just add spaces.